# Node.js Readline not writing to output file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream

### Background

I am trying to read a several GB sized file line by line. I want to process each line and after that write it to a file. I don't want to ( nor can I ) put everything into memory.

It is important that the order in which i read a line is the order in which I write it to a file.

### Code

To achieve this I tried using Node.js [Readline interface](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

```
const fs = require( "fs" ),
    readline = require( "readline" );

const readStream = fs.createReadStream( "./logs/report.csv" );
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( "./logs/out.csv", { encoding: "utf8"} );

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream,
    output: writeStream,
    terminal: false,
    historySize: 0
});

rl.on( "line", function(line) {

    //Do your stuff ...
    const transformedLine = line.toUpperCase();
    console.log(transformedLine);

    //Then write to outstream
    rl.write(transformedLine );
});
```

### Problem

As you can see, I am trying to read a line, parse it, and write it into a file called `out.csv`.

The problem is that the output file is always empty. Nothing is ever written into it.

I have read all the methods, events and options, but clearly I am missing something.

### Question

Why is this code not writing into the file?

Comment: Setting "terminal" as true will write the line to the file writestream.

Comment: It will write it without any transformation whatsoever and limited to the history size. Both things I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

With the current code, I am actually feeding `Readline` with `transformedLine` again.

This is not what I want. What I should be doing is to write directly to `writeStream`.

```
rl.on( "line", function(line) {
    console.log(line);

    //Do your stuff ...
    const transformedLine = line.toUpperCase();
    console.log(transformedLine);

    //Then write to outstream
    writeStream.write( transformedLine );
});
```

This will produce an output file respecting the order of input.

For a more detailed discussion on the stream mechanics and internal buffers see:

- https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1292

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late for the question, but for anyone who reads this:

If you `write` on every `read` and your write speed is slower than read speed you'll still bloat memory. Though not as much as by reading entire file to memory.

You should use `pipe` with `stream.Transform` instead of `readline`. Reason being that pipe processes data at the phase of the slowest participant in flow and so won't bloat memory.

```js
const stream = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./logs/report.csv");
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./logs/report.csv");

const transformer = new stream.Transform({
  // buffer is a chunk of stream, enc is type of chunk, done is a callback when transform is done
  transform(buffer, enc, done){
    const lines = buffer.toString().split('\n');
    const transformedChunkAsString = lines.map(workYourMagicAndReturnFormattedLine).join('\n');
    const transformedBuffer = Buffer.from(transformedChunkAsString);
    this.push(transformedBuffer);
    done();
  }
})

readStream.pipe(transformStream).pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: Only issue with this approach is that chunk might be split in the middle of the line and thus regex might not match what you're looking for. You can how ever, store last line, if not complete in a variable outside transform function and prepend that to next chunk

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
const fs = require( "fs" ),
readline = require( "readline" );

const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./logs/report.csv");
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./logs/report.csv");

readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: Doing this will create a duplicate of my file. This is not what I want. It will also do it asynchronously, not preserving any order whatsoever if I try to transform the data.